# Line height animation for large body of text

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, css-transitions, easing

I'm designing a website for my business and I'm trying desperately to make an interactive design concept work.

I set my logo in white against a body of text. [Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UnYP.png). I liked it so much I used the body of text as the entire sidebar.

Now I've been trying to animate the line-height property of the background text to ["fade in" the white logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvHpZ.png).

The problem is, in order to have enough lines of text to make the logo and sidebar text stand out, I have to have a big chunk of text.

Right now, I'm using a body of text about 6700 lines long.

I've tried the two basic methods for animating line height changes. However, the change is always sudden and slightly delayed.

1) I added a `transition: all` statement to the CSS for the text:

```
#text {
text-align: right;
font-size: 30%;
height: 100px;
line-height: 7.0 em;
transition: all 500ms ease;
```

I then wrote a function to change the line height with a range slider. The slider works, but there is no transition - the line height change is instantaneous, even when it's only one step (0.01em).

2) I downloaded and installed the `jQuery` easings plugin from gsgd.co.uk. I then made it so the line height of the text goes down every time the logo is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logo").click(function(){
        $("#text").animate({
        "line-height": "-=0.5em"},
        1000,
        "easeInOutQuad"
        );
    });
});
```

Before I tried this out, I tested `easeInOutBounce` on three lines of text. The easing plugin worked, though it wasn't as buttery smooth as I hoped. And on the big wall of text, the line height change is still instantaneous. In fact, it buffers; the text will shrink to a single line, I'll bring it back to 4em with the slider, then the line height will *continue* shrinking (in sudden bursts), like it hasn't processed all the clicks.

So I assume the browser is at its limits (I'm using Chrome BTW). I really like this idea though.

Is there any way something like this could be made to work? And if not, is there a known threshold for how much text you can try to animate before the browser gives up?

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle for your code

Comment: I've never made a jsfiddle. Do you want it with the entire 6700-line text?

Comment: Here you go. I can't get the slider to work now for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/6yuqus8r/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for making the JSFiddle, although we can do it completely by using jQuery with the easing plugin, it is better to use CSS3 wherever possible, so I have.

Changed the CSS:

```
#text {
text-align: /*justify*/ right;
font-size: 30%;
height: 50px;
line-height: 0.5em;
transition: all 2000ms ease;
}

#text.anime {
    line-height: 5em;
}
```

Changed the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logo").click(function(){
        // you can use addClass or toggleClass if you want to toggle it
        //$('#text').addClass('anime');
        $('#text').toggleClass('anime');
    });
});
```

You can check the JSFiddle Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/sameersemna/74fg3tn1/1/

Hope you got what you wanted :)